How to make a Discord bot make a channel when a command is made
I'm confused on how to make my Discord bot make a new text channel called 'General 2'. When I do !setup the command works perfectly fine but I don't know how to make it make a new channel.
I tried some Youtube tutorials, but it ended up either causing errors or doing nothing. It kept on making this error:

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

require('dotenv').config()
const { Client, IntentsBitField, StringSelectMenuBuilder,StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder,ChannelType, Guild} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
  ]
})

client.on('ready', (c) => {
  console.log('Server Setup is ready')
})

//What i've tried
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!setup') {
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;
    server.channels.create(name, "text")
  }
})

client.login(process.env.Token)


I've not personally used discord.js, but looking at the documentation for channels.create() it states that it expects an object containing configuration data, not 2 arguments. I'd start there.

Thank you soo much Rocy McCrossan, this is the first time i used documentation so im kinda confused on how to use them. But THANK YOU!

.create needs only 1 object argument.
server.channels.create({ name })

